# SQL Server MOD equivalent

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simple question in regards to `MOD` alternative in SQL Server. I know SQL Server `MOD` is written as `%` but that usually requires a `number % number`.

My question is how can I use the `%` when I have these clauses in the code:

```
SELECT 
    NULL,
    LeagueID,
    COUNT(1),
    1,
    COUNT(1),
    1
FROM   
    Team
GROUP BY 
    LeagueID
HAVING 
    MOD( COUNT(1), 2 ) > 0
```

OR

```
CASE away_idx
               WHEN num_teams + num_fake - 1
               THEN away_idx
               ELSE MOD( away_idx + 1, num_teams + num_fake - 1 )
               END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't quite understand the logic of your query.

anyway . . . here is how you used the MOD %

```
SELECT   NULL, LeagueID, COUNT(1), 1, COUNT(1), 1 
FROM     Team 
GROUP BY LeagueID 
HAVING   COUNT(1) % 2  > 0
```